# Postgres - How to drop all tables in a database except for 3

Tags: postgresql

I know that to drop a table in a database is as follows, but if I have a database that has over a dozen tables and I only need to keep 3 of them, am I able to delete all but the 3 with only one command?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS c_note RESTRICT;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but you need to enumerate over all the tables you want to drop. There's no command to drop all but 3. So, if you had the following tables:

1. foo
2. bar
3. baz
4. narf
5. poit
6. troz

And you wanted to drop the first three and keep the last three, you would use the command:

```
 DROP TABLE foo, bar, baz;
```

If you know the tables all exist, there's no need for `IF EXISTS`, although it won't hurt. `RESTRICT` is also not needed -- that's the default (the opposite is `CASCADE`, where you also drop dependant objects).

[SQL Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptable.html)

Answer (score 5):

The following query will simmply delete all the tables but keep your schema

```
select 'drop table if exists ' || tablename || ' cascade;' 
    from pg_tables 
    where schemaname = 'public'
```

Write down a query where you can skip three tables by name

```
select 'drop table if exists ' || tablename || ' cascade;' 
from pg_tables 
where schemaname = 'public' 
and tablename not in (:tbaleNamesToKeep);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had 192 tables, so manually writing all tables out was infeasible. My strategy was to select all table names, remove the tables I wanted to keep and then run a `DROP` on the rest.

**1. Select all tables**

```
SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables
```

When you select, copy and paste the results, the text should look something like this:

```
"table1"
"table2"
"table3"
...
```

**2. Remove the tables you want to keep**

So let's say you want to keep `table2`, you just remove the line.

```
"table1"
"table3"
...
```

**3. Add commas with text replacement**

Replace `"\n` with `",\n`.
To do this, I use [regexr.com](https://regexr.com), but any text editor will do.

```
"table1",
"table3",
...
```

**4. Create and run the final PSQL statement**

```
DROP TABLE
"table1",
"table3",
...
```